# X authority bypass

Tags: linux, security, xserver

I'm trying to write an application that runs as a daemon and monitors
running X sessions. Right now I'm struggling to find documentation
regarding the X security model. Specifically, I'm attempting to
connect to running X displays from my daemon process. Calling
`XOpenDisplay(dispName)` doesn't work, I guess because my process
doesn't have permission to connect to this display. After a bit of
research, it looks like I need to do something with xauth.

In my test environment, the X server is started like this:

```
/usr/bin/X -br -nolisten tcp :0 vt7 -auth /var/run/xauth/A:0-QBEVDj
```

That file contains a single entry, that looks like this:

```
#ffff##:  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

by adding an entry to `~/.Xauthority` with the same hex key, I can
connect to the X server. However, this is difficult because I need to
programmatically find the auth file the X server is using (the
location of which I guess will change from distro to distro, and
probably from one boot to the next), then query it, then write a new
auth file. If the process is running as a daemon, it might not have a
home directory, so how do I know where to write the new entries to?

Ideally, what I'm looking for is a way to bypass the need to have the
xauth cookie in `~/.Xauthority`, or even to know what the cookie is at
all. I realise that this is unlikely - what good is a security model
if it's easily bypassed? but I'm hoping someone on this list may have
a few good ideas. Is there a way to specify that my process is
privileged and thus should automatically be given access to any
display on the local machine?

Comment: I discovered this Q in the process of solving a similar issue myself, and discovered in some system code a that provides a way to find the .xauthority file the X display was initialised with, and made some code that may helpful: http://blog.fox.geek.nz/2012/10/granting-root-access-to-all-xorg-x11.html

Comment: On a more fundamental level, you seem to be looking for ways to bypass security barriers which were put in there for good reasons. A less intrusive approach is to have your users run a client which connects to your daemon via some RPC mechanism. You can make it run by default for all users from the system-wide X session hooks, which also makes it possible -- but cumbersome -- for some users to opt out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to use a home directory if you specify an `XAUTHORITY` environment variable, which specifies the location of the `.Xauthority` file. Read the `xauth` man page.

But, in general, it's hard to locate the auth file, for the reasons you mentioned; also, this "fishing for auth tokens" approach would only work for local displays.

With regard to letting root (or some other user) connect to an X server willy-nilly, you'd probably have to patch the source code to do this, and you'd have to use something like `getpeereid` to obtain the connecting user's uid/gid (this only works on Unix-domain sockets, which I presume would be the type used for local connections, anyway).

Comment: Thanks. I am only interested in local connections. I'm able to modify local configuration files when I install my application, but modifying the X server source code and patching the X server upon installation is out of the question.

Answer (score 1):

Xauth is not the only security mechanism for X

There is also another one (less secure) that just performs IP based authentication 
(See [xhost](http://www.xfree86.org/current/xhost.1.html)).

So if you switch your X server to this less secure mode it will trust any connections coming
from the defined set of IPs.

This way you do not need to deal with Xauthority at all.

Comment: Thanks. I'm aware of the xhost-based authentication mechanism. Perhaps this is the best way to go. Ideally I don't want to change the existing authentication mechanism at all, since I'm now messing with the user's configuration (can you imagine the uproar amongst security-concious users when I change to the least secure authentication mechanism so my application can run?).

Comment: I will say that I would never run an application that required me to switch off xauth, so I understand the whole "uproar amongst security-conscious users".

Comment: Okay. Here's a compromise that probably won't make sysadmins want to kill you. Maybe. Use xhost and enable access from a private IP (e.g., 127.1.2.3). Get the sysadmin to set up firewall rules that only allow connections to 127.1.2.3 if the socket belongs to root (or whatever). Done.